# Material angular, md vs mat , @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.11 template parse errors

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've just updated angular material via NPM (@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.11-53c42a4)

Now my apps doesn't work anymore, because syntax differences. I look up the documents what's changed, but there isn't  much information out there about this issues. 
 I've tried to replace all the 
**import{ Md ** Module, etc. } from "@angular/material"**
 with
 
**import {Mat ** Module} from "@angular/material"** in **app.module** file.

I've still got Template parse errors. [image: An example of many errors I've got]

My question is: Where do I begin to solve this problem?

I was planning to :

1) Change all the import Md ** Module -> Mat ** Module

2) Try to trial and error change all the HTML tags

---

Update:
Through trial and errors I've solved partial of this question. What I did is following:

1. change all the **import{ Md ** Module, etc. } from "@angular/material"** into 
   **import {Mat ** Module,etc.} from "@angular/material"**
2. Go through all the *.html files of the components and changed the HTML-tags.
    `<md-expansion-panel></md-expansion-panel>
    <md-select><md-option></md-option></md-select>... etc` 
    into 
    `<mat-expansion-panel></mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-select><mat-option></mat-option></mat-select> ...etc.` 
   The prefix `md` is changed into `mat`. I think there's no easy way to solve this.

Comment: This is perfectly fine question, and one probably everyone who just upgraded angular is facing. The breaking changes are documented here:

https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.11

Comment: Agreed. This should be reopened. 
in the documentation that chrismarx points to there is a link to a tool that automatically changes all md prefixes to mat.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-prefix-updater

Comment: The close reason is **too broad** ? I don't think so.